# CSS for label text when checkbox input is inside label?

Tags: html, css

I am using a method to style my checkboxes which requires the checkbox input to be placed inside the label, rather than as a sibling. I would like to make the label text bold if the input is checked but I'm not sure if this is possible with straight CSS since there is no parent selector and the input is inside the label. Would it be possible to modify the CSS of the label text without using Javascript?

```css
label {
  padding-left:35px;
  position:relative;
}
input {
  position:absolute;
  opacity:0;
  cursor:pointer;
}
  label .checkmark {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:25px;
    width:25px;
    background:#ccc;
  }
    input:checked ~ .checkmark {
      background:green;
    }
```

```html
<label>
  Label text (should be bold when checked)
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```css
label {
  padding-left: 35px;
  position: relative;
}

input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label .checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background: #ccc;
}

input:checked~.checkmark {
  background: green;
}

input:checked~.text {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
   <span class="text">Label text (should be bold when checked)</span>
</label>
```

Comment: So simple it never even crossed my mind :X haha, thank you!